# ORACLE IIF Statement

Tags: oracle, conditional-operator, iif

I get an error while writing the IIF statement, table and the statement given below.

Statement:

```
SELECT IIF(EMP_ID=1,'True','False') from Employee;
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE SCOTT.EMPLOYEE
(
   EMP_ID       INTEGER                          NOT NULL,
   EMP_FNAME    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)                NOT NULL,
   EMP_LNAME    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)                NOT NULL,
   EMP_ADDRESS  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)                NOT NULL,
   EMP_PHONE    CHAR(10 BYTE)                    NOT NULL,
   EMP_GENDER   CHAR(1 BYTE)
)
```

Error:

> 00907-missing right parantheses

Please provide your inputs.

Comment: AFAIK, Oracle does not have an IIF function. You can use CASE WHEN instead: `select CASE WHEN emp_id = 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END from employee`

Answer (score 80):

Oracle doesn't provide such IIF Function. 
Instead, try using one of the following alternatives:

[DECODE Function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm):

```
SELECT DECODE(EMP_ID, 1, 'True', 'False') from Employee
```

[CASE Function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EMP_ID = 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END from Employee
```

Answer (score 23):

Two other alternatives:

3. a combination of [`NULLIF`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions102.htm) and [`NVL2`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions106.htm). You can only use this if `emp_id` is `NOT NULL`, which it is in your case:

   ```
   select nvl2(nullif(emp_id,1),'False','True') from employee;
   ```
4. simple [`CASE` expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) (Mt. Schneiders used a so-called searched `CASE` expression)

   ```
   select case emp_id when 1 then 'True' else 'False' end from employee;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In PL/SQL, there is a trick to use the undocumented `OWA_UTIL.ITE` function.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
    x   VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
    x := owa_util.ite('a' = 'b','T','F');
    dbms_output.put_line(x);
END;
/

F

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```