# Oracle Equivalent for IIF in Access SQL?

Tags: oracle

In access I used to use IIF function in SQL queries

```
Select iif(X>=0,'Positive','Negative') from TableName;
```

Is there any equivalent for that in Oracle ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORACLE IIF Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791684/oracle-iif-statement)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `CASE`

```
select case 
         when x >= 0 then 'Positive'
         else 'Negative'
       end as sign
from tablename;
```