# truncate integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I got a task to chop an integer by 1 digit.
For example, If the new limit is 3 digits then 1234 will become 999 after the change. if the before change value is 12345 then it should becomes 999 after changes. if the pre-change value is 564 then it will remain unchanged.

This has to be done on Oracle as well as SQL server. the truc function only truncates decimal but not integer.

What is the best way to do this in SQL, PL/SQL or T-SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jamiec: Max 3 digit number is always `999`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for T-SQL. Converting it to other sql dialects should just be as simple as finding the similar methods

```
declare @numDigits INT = 3;
declare @maxNumber INT = POWER(10,@numDigits)-1 -- gets "999" when using 3 digits, 9999 when using 4 etc


DECLARE @input INT = 1234
DECLARE @output INT = IIF(@input>@maxNumber,@maxNumber,@input)

SELECT @output -- selects 999
```

Oracle does have the [`POWER`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/power.php) function, but [does not have the ternary/IIF function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791684/oracle-iif-statement)

Comment: Hi, Jamiec and bumble_bee_tuna, thank you all so much for the clever ideas. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use case statements for this like:

```
SELECT CASE [yourInt] >= 1000 THEN 999 ELSE [yourInt] END AS 'UpperLimit'
From [YouTable]
```